# The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise<T> type Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, observable

I am trying to create a guard in order to validate if user is allowed to navigate to a route based on busines logic.

But I am getting The return type of an async function or method must be the global Promise type.ts

```js
async canActivate(
  next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {

  const idCliente = +next.paramMap.get('id');

  const usuario = await this.authService.getUserSubject().pipe(first()).toPromise()
  const cliente = await this.clienteService.obtenerCliente(idCliente).pipe(first()).toPromise()

  return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(usuario.empresaId === cliente.empresaId)
  })
}
```

Comment: That's correct, an async function can't return an observable, boolean or URL tree - it *always* returns a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the return type is `Promise` you might want to modify the return type:

```js
 async canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
  ...
 }
```

It would be more advisable to use Observable (rather than converting the results from both `getUserSubject` and `obtenerCliente` into Promises) as demonstrated below:

```js
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
  const idCliente = +next.paramMap.get('id');

  return combineLatest(
    this.authService.getUserSubject(),
    this.clienteService.obtenerCliente(idCliente)
  )
    .pipe(
      first(),
      map(([usuario, cliente]) => usuario.empresaId === cliente.empresaId)
    )
}
```

Comment: You are correct, silly mistake in the return type. Thanks for the extra tip!